# Special UIScrollView with multiple objects (3) on each page

Tags: iphone, ios4, uiscrollview, coverflow

What I want to accomplish is something like this:

[image]

Two different scrollViews, and each one scrolls horizontically. Each showing 3 images, and a half one (or 1/3th) piece of the next image in the datasource of the scrollview.

Does anyone know how to accomplish such a scrollview?

I also want to be able to tap an image to flip it and show some information and a button to the detail. (See lower scrollview).
Tapping it again would just show back the image, much like the coverflow ui inside itunes, but without the coverflow being 3D...

Any help is welcome :)

Thanks in advance,

Lewion

Answer (score 0):

Scroll view doesn't have a datasource. What you are looking for is standard scrolling and nothing special.. So it is definitely doable... Check the [scrolling](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Scrolling/Introduction/Intro.html) and [photo scroller](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoScroller/Introduction/Intro.html) sample codes from apple developer samples. For more implementations of scroll view check the [scroll view suite](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ScrollViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html) sample code and read the [scroll view programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/Introduction/Introduction.html).

The flip animation is also a standard animation for a view and is easily doable. For example, create a utility application for iphone. It has a flip side view. See how that animation is done.